# Where can I ask questions about web design?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Currently, I'm working as asp.net web developer. But actually, I'm so poor in design. Where can I ask questions about my web design?

I can show the screen-shot or html , css code of my web page.

What I want to ask is about layout, color, font-styles, etc. I just want to get some advice from experienced web designers.

Kindly help me , thanks :)

Comment: i can show only `screen-shoot , html ,css` because my web site is currently in localhost , not published yet :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Crap, no wonder the question seemed familiar, I've already answered it before...